# Send Data from Android App to Google App Engine Python, Need code for both Android App as well as the Python code on the server side

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, http-post

I need the code for sending data from android app to google app engine server (python).
I'm not able to get the HttpPost request correctly so please help me with the code for both android app as well as Python code at the server side in google app engine

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: have you done any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Google Cloud Endpoint to communicate between Server and Android client. Sample code can be found here.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

and for android client:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android